# locked s3db-journal

Tags: sqlite, networking

a few days we had a strange error with sqlite. We use a sqlite database on a network share with several computers accessing it. Our client reported, that the database is gone. A quick overview showed, that the database was still there but no computer could access it. It also showed a s3db-journal file indicating that someone is/was accessing the db when something happened. The thing that is strange - the s3db-journal file was locked by the file system (we could not copy/delete it). After restarting all applications, the locked file disappeared as it should be.

How does this happen? We would like to deduct somehow how our client got into this situation. We know, that there was a corrupt network cabeling to one of the computers.

Thank you for your help.

Tobias

---

To clarify this: several = up to 10 computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The database-component (zeos) threw an exception and we tried a rollback. Due to the way the component was designed, this is only allowed when you started a transaction. If you don't you get the locked s3db-journal file.

In the end we learned 2 things: never rollback when you did not start a transaction, second - there is a function InTransaction from zeos for that.

Answer (score 0):

From the "[Appropriate uses for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)" page:

> If you have many client programs accessing a common database over a network, you should consider using a client/server database engine instead of SQLite. SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not be great. Also, the file locking logic of many network filesystems implementation contains bugs (on both Unix and Windows). If file locking does not work like it should, it might be possible for two or more client programs to modify the same part of the same database at the same time, resulting in database corruption. Because this problem results from bugs in the underlying filesystem implementation, there is nothing SQLite can do to prevent it.
>
> A good rule of thumb is that you should avoid using SQLite in situations where the same database will be accessed simultaneously from many computers over a network filesystem.

It very well might be a bug in the network filesystem you're using.  Either way, the SQLite developers explicitly recommend against using databases on network filesystems.

Comment: I know and we are working on it. In the mean time - sqlite seems better than ms access (at least sqlite supports transaction).